# How can I read .rdata file and write .csv files from it

Tags: r

I am a completely a beginner in r language. I need to read a .rdata file that contains a list of several matrices. The length of the list is 551 and the matrices it contains have the same dimensions of 462 x 961.

I want to write each of these matrices in a separate .csv file hence I will finally have 551 .csv files.
I am not able to do that. Somehow, I was able to read the .rdata file by using the following code.

```
load("/home/mondal/Documents/Dataset/seismic/seismic.RData", ex <- new.env())
ls.str(ex) 
print(length(ex[1].inline))
```

But then I don't know how to proceed. It will be very helpful if someone can give me some working code to do that. You can visualize my data structure from the image.

[image]

Comment: What do you want to name these CSV files?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a loop where you set the path for where you want the data to be stored + the file name:

```
for(i in 1:551){
  path = paste("/home/mondal/RestOfThePath/FileNumber",i,".txt",sep="")
  write(inline[[i]], file=path)}
```

Comment: If it solved your question, accept the answer to mark the post as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solve the problem like this:

```
load("/home/mondal/Documents/Dataset/seismic/seismic.RData", ex <- new.env())
ls.str(ex) 
print(length(ex))


for(i in 1:length(inline)){
    path = paste("/home/mondal/Documents/Dataset/seismic/Netherland_Data_CSV/FileNumber_",i,".csv",sep=",")
    df <- data.frame(inline[[i]])
    write.csv(df, file=path, row.names = FALSE)
}
```